# Elasticsearch malformed query error with aggs

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, kibana, aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I'm facing some errors with DSL query builder and aggregations.

Tried several approaches and none of them seem to work.

If I remove `aggs` clause, the query works seamlessly.

Queries below return error: `[bool] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]`

```json
{
    "query": {
    "bool": {
        "filter": [
        {
            "range": {
            "json.@timestamp": {
                "gt": "2021-08-22T00:00:00.000Z",
                "lt": "2022-10-22T13:41:09.000Z"
            }
            }
        },
        {
            "term": {
            "json.path": "/api/v1/discover"
            }
        },
        {
            "wildcard": {
            "container.image.name": {
                "value": "*prod*"
            }
            }
        }
        ]
    }
    },
    "aggs": {
    "totalCount": {
        "sum": {
        "field": "count"
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Using `aggs` inside `body` also does not work.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "json.@timestamp": {
              "gt": "2021-08-22T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lt": "2022-10-22T13:41:09.000Z"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "json.path": "/api/v1/discover"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "container.image.name": {
              "value": "*prod*"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "body": {
    "aggs": {
      "group_by_id": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "cloud.image.id"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not even a basic `aggs` example will succeed.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "objects": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "json.path"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This one returns error: `[1:16806] unknown field [aggs]`

```json
{
  "query": {
    "aggs": {
      "my-agg-name": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "json.path"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm on `Elastic Cloud v7.16.2`

Comment: Hi Thiago, I have been testing your first query and it is working for me.
Would you care to explain us a bit how you are testing your queries ?

Comment: @Paulo hey, just found out what the problem is.. Aggregations will only work on Dev Tools page. It will not work on Dicover page Seach box. Sorry for the newbie question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out what the problem is... Aggregations will only work on Dev Tools page. It will not work on Discover page Seach box.